# How do I detect multiple keypresses in python all at the same time?

Tags: python, keypress

I want to move my robot car diagonally and so to achieve that I want to detect if 'w' is pressed along with 'd' or 'a'.

If I want to use 'w', 'a', 's', 'd' as my keys.

what I have now is like this

```
from curtsies import Input  
with Input(keynames='curses') as input_generator:
    for key in input_generator:
        print(key)
        if key == 'w':
             #move forward
        if key == 's':
             #move backward
        if key == 'a':
             #move left
        if key == 'd':
             #move right
        if key == ' ':
             #stop
```

But I want my program to be something like this :

```
while True:
    while keypressed('w'):
        #move forward
    while keypressed('s'):
        #move backward
    while keypressed('a'):
        #move left
    while keypressed('d'):
        #move right
    while keypressed('w')&&keypressed('a'):
        #move forward left diagonally
    while keypressed('w')&&keypressed('d'):
        #move forward right diagonally
```

Also i want to know when the keys are released so i can make the car stop. In essence I want the car to work exactly how a car would function in a game like GTA or NFS.....

What would be the easiest way to achieve this? The lighter the code, the better......

Comment: You could try using `and`: `while keypressed('w') and keypressed('a'):`. As for detecting if the key is released, like the `keypressed`, you can use the `keyrelease`. I don't use the module you use, so maybe it wont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach to do it is to use pygame module. `pygame.key.get_pressed()` returns the list of all the keys pressed at one time:

e.g. for multiple key press

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_w] and keys[pygame.K_a]:
    #Do something
```

More details in [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed.).

Answer (score 1):

If a small timeout is acceptable, a possible approach is using the [send method](https://curtsies.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Input.html#curtsies.Input.send), like in the following example:

```py
from curtsies import Input, events

with Input(keynames="curtsies", sigint_event=True) as input_generator:
    while True:
        key = input_generator.send(0.1)
        if key:
            print(key)
        if key and (
            key in ("q", "Q", "<ESC>", "<Ctrl-d>", "<SigInt Event>")
            or isinstance(key, events.SigIntEvent)
        ):
            print("Terminated")
            break
        if key and key == "<UP>":
            print('move up')
        print('.', end='', flush=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using the `keyboard` module

first we import the module by putting in `import keyboard`

then we put it in a `while True:` loop

and in the while true loop we put `if keyboard.is_pressed("n") and keyboard.is_pressed("m"):`

and inside the if function we put the code that is to be executed e.g `print("n and m pressed")`

so the final code is:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("n") and keyboard.is_pressed("m"):
        print("n and m pressed")
```