# why is this code not working with library keyboard

Tags: python, web, keyboard

If I press ctrl and alt at the same time, my program does nothing. I want if I press ctrl and alt at the same time python will automatically refresh the page 100 times.
Does anyone know why this isn't working and what I need to change?

```
from pynput import keyboard


def on_press(key):
   if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False  # stop listener
   try:
        k = key.char  # single-char keys
   except Exception as ex:
        k = key.name  # other keys
   if k in ['ctl'+'alt']:  # keys of interest
        # self.keys.append(k)  # store it in global-like variable
        print('Key pressed: ' + k)


listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()  # start to listen on a separate thread
listener.join()  # remove if main thread is polling self.keys
```

Comment: perhaps, change `+` to `,` (could do in both places actually, but I mean the one where you have a list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been testing your example and it seems that the library distinguishes between left and right 'Ctrl' and 'Alt'.

[image: Here when I pressed 'Ctrl left']

You should also note that only ONE KEY is detected, so the expression '`if k in ['ctl'+'alt']:`' will never be TRUE.

If you change it to '`if k in ['ctrl_l', 'alt_l']:`' (note that I changed the names of the keys as I said before that every key is different) at least one of them will be recognised. The approach given to achieve your goal is not the right one. Check this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64227080/14734258) or something like [this](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/20):

```
from pynput import keyboard

# The key combination to check
COMBINATION = {keyboard.Key.ctrl_l, keyboard.Key.alt_l}

# The currently active modifiers
current = set()


def on_press(key):
    if key in COMBINATION:
        current.add(key)
        if all(k in current for k in COMBINATION):
            print('PRESSED')
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        listener.stop()


def on_release(key):
    try:
        current.remove(key)
    except KeyError:
        pass


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Do you also know how to get multiple buttons to be pressed by python?

Comment: I updated the answer with code that worked for me! Try it and tell me.